# git $Id$ how to ensure it is updated?

Tags: git, gitlab

In my repository I used the .gitattributes and append $Id$ hashes to my files. However in a typical commmit

```
$git commit -a -m ""
$git push origin master
```

I notice that the embedded $Id$ in the modified files dont change. A further

```
$git checkout modified_file.txt
```

is necessary to ensure the updated $Id$.

Is there a command to update all the hashes automatically?

Comment: I hope that an empty commit message isn't a typical commit. ;)

Answer (score 1):

`ident` and other [effects attributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_effects) work only on check-out. To force checkout remove `.git/index` and run `git reset --hard`.